# fish_complete_cd.fish (line 35): builtin cd $i

Tags: macos, fish

I've upgraded to Yosemite and installed the latest Fish app.

All works fine, except the TAB for autocompletion.

If I am in the `~` folder, for example, and there's a folder in it called vagrant, then when I do `cd vag` and press `TAB` I receive the following error:

`The directory '~' does not exist
/Applications/fish.app/Contents/Resources/base/share/fish/functions/__fish_complete_cd.fish (line 35):          builtin cd $i
                                                                                                                               ^
in function '__fish_complete_cd',
    called on standard input,`

in command substitution
    called on standard input,

cd: The directory '~/workspace' does not exist
/Applications/fish.app/Contents/Resources/base/share/fish/functions/__fish_complete_cd.fish (line 35):          builtin cd $i
                                                                                                                               ^
in function '__fish_complete_cd',
    called on standard input,

in command substitution
    called on standard input,

However FISH will show the list of folder and I will be able to navigate to it. It's just the inconvenience of the error message.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe it is a Yosemite issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. What about trying the [installer](http://fishshell.com/files/2.1.1/fish.pkg) instead of downloading the Fish.app? I am using Yosemite too.

Answer (score 1):

I tried reinstalling it using all types: homebrew, app, and package and got the same error.

Then I started debugging, as indicated in the error message and found that the part having problems was dealing with CDPATH.

On my machine the CDPATH was `export CDPATH="~:~/workspace"`.

Changing the CDPATH to `export CDPATH="/Users/asantos/workspace"` worked, so the problem is the expansion of tilde in the CDPATH.